# GeForce 2060 not detected on a new Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.04, nvidia-geforce

I've just bought a new laptop with a GeForce 2060, and installed 20.04
But my GPU is not detected at all, the only GPU he detects is the Intel Graphics.

`glxinfo | grep vendor` gave me only this:

```
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
```

I've disabled secure boot, as I've seen this in other helps, but it didn't helped.

I've tried to install the proprietary NVidia driver, but when it's installed, X does not start, I only acces the command lines to uninstall it.

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` gives:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Tongfang Hongkong Limited Device 1097
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Tongfang Hongkong Limited Device 1097
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Thanks, but i've already done that, I have written it in my message, but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I don't see any Nvidia drivers installed.  How did you install them?

Comment: I have installed them with the .deb file that I have downloaded on the nvidia site, but I had to uninstall them since I could not start the X server with it installed

Comment: That was a wrong way. Run `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, or use Programs & Updates -> Additionsl Drivers.

Comment: The command you gave me give me a "No drivers found for installation.". And in additional drivers i only have a line: "Interl corporation : unknown", but nothing Nvidia.

Comment: Then run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`.

Comment: Thanks a 1000 times! It worked

Answer (score 1):

Manually install Nvidia drivers by

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

terminal command.

Probably the maintainers forgot to add the `2060` to the list for autoinstall.